# Parametrized traits c++

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, traits

I am learning templates from book: 
C++ Templates, The complete guide ( Vandevoorde, Josuttis).
On chapter 15.1.3. is the following example:

```
// traits/accum5.hpp 

#ifndef ACCUM_HPP 
#define ACCUM_HPP 

#include "accumtraits4.hpp" 

template <typename T, 
          typename AT = AccumulationTraits<T> > 
class Accum { 
  public: 
    static typename AT::AccT accum (T const* beg, T const* end) { 
        typename AT::AccT total = AT::zero(); 
        while (beg != end) { 
            total += *beg; 
            ++beg; 
        } 
        return total; 
    } 
}; 

#endif // ACCUM_HPP
```

As is often the case, we can introduce convenience functions to simplify the interface:

```
template <typename T> 
inline 
typename AccumulationTraits<T>::AccT accum (T const* beg, 
                                            T const* end) 
{ 
    return Accum<T>::accum(beg, end); 
} 

template <typename Traits, typename T>
inline 
typename Traits::AccT accum (T const* beg, T const* end) 
{ 
    return Accum<T, Traits>::accum(beg, end); 
}
```

This is point, where I got lost. 
Can anybody explain how the second interface function works, why is it good idea to use it, when is it useful and how to call it?

thanks!

Comment: OK. But what does your book say?

Comment: they say just: 
As is often the case, we can introduce convenience functions to simplify the interface
thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Specifically answer the question, the second form allows you to select the traits class at the call site, eg:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct AccumulationTraits
{
    using AccT = T;
    static constexpr AccT zero() { return AccT(0); }
};

template <typename T,
typename AT = AccumulationTraits<T> >
class Accum {
public:
    static typename AT::AccT accum (T const* beg, T const* end) {
        typename AT::AccT total = AT::zero();
        while (beg != end) {
            total += *beg;
            ++beg;
        }
        return total;
    }
};

template <typename T>
inline
typename AccumulationTraits<T>::AccT accum (T const* beg,
                                            T const* end)
{
    return Accum<T>::accum(beg, end);
}

template <typename Traits, typename T>
inline
typename Traits::AccT accum (T const* beg, T const* end)
{
    return Accum<T, Traits>::accum(beg, end);
}



template<class T>
struct Doubler
{
    struct AccT {
        AccT(T t) : _t(t) {}
        operator T() const { return _t; }
        AccT& operator+=(T t) { _t += (t * 2); return *this; }
        T _t;
    };
    static constexpr AccT zero() { return AccT(0); }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    // first form selects default traits class
    auto a = accum(&v[0], &v[v.size()]);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    // second form selects any other traits class
    auto b = accum<Doubler<int>>(&v[0], &v[v.size()]);
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
45
90
```

Answer (score 1):

The point is that function templates allow for the deduction of template parameters from the function call expression, whereas there is no such analogue for class templates.

If you only had the class template, you would need to spell out the template parameters yourself:

```
int arr_sum = Accum<int>::accum(arr, arr + len);
//                 ^^^^^
```

By complementing the class template with a helper function template, we can let template argument deduction figure the type out:

```
int arr_sum = accum(arr, arr + len);    // Deduces T = int
```

This is a common pattern. Examples in the standard library are `make_pair`, `make_tuple`, `make_optional`, `make_move_iterator`, and `make_reverse_iterator`. For example:

```
auto x = std::make_optional(10);

// same as:
std::optional<int> x(10);
```

A more striking example is `make_reverse_iterator`:

```
auto it = f();
auto rit = std::make_reverse_iterator(it);

// same as:
std::map<int, std::string>::iterator it = f();
std::reverse_iterator<std::map<int, std::string>::iterator> rit(it);
```

In each case, the return type depends in some way on a class template specialization, but the type-deducing helper function template allows us to never have to say the class template name at all.

Comment: thanks! would it be possible to provide example on how to call interface with 2nd option?

Comment: @petertutuk: Sure. You can specify some template parameters and leave the remaining ones to be deduced, so you can say `accum<Trait>(begin, end)`.